# I get a Cross-Origin Request blocked when trying to use pdf.js

Tags: html, pdf.js

I try to use pdf.js to read a local pdf file.

I added this script tag:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.8.335/build/pdf.min.js">       </script>
```

and I got this simple console.log to see if it works:

```html
<script>pdfjsLib.getDocument('livret-Krismenn.pdf').then(doc => {
        console.og('this file has ' + doc._pdfInfo.numPages +        'pages')
    })  </script>
```

but it doesn't.

The reason given by my browser (firefox): The CORS request doesn't use http.

I looked it up and found solutions talking about:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

but I have no clue what to do with that...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can't read file from local system directly due to security issues. You need to run a simple web server to load pdf file form. This option you mentioned should be set on webserver side not your side. Try running simple static webserver available with npm,...

You can also use `FileReader` api to read files on system.